# Helmholtz Equation in a rectangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

lately I've been doing some self study on solutions to boundary value problems and I have run into a little bit of a snag. I'm trying to solve the following boundary value problem involving the Helmholtz equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + ku(x,y) = 0, 0 \leq x \leq L, 0\leq y \leq W$$
$$u(x,0) = u(x,W) = 0, 0 \leq x \leq L$$
$$u(0,y) = u(L,y) = 0, 0 \leq y \leq W$$
where $k$ is a non-zero constant. My first attempt was to separate variables. Letting $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ we get
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = -\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} - k.$$
Because the left hand side is $x$-dependent and the right hand side is $y$-dependent, this equation implies
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = -\lambda = -\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} - k$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant. From here we solve the boundary value problem
$$X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0, \ \ \ X(0) = X(L) = 0.$$
This boundary value problem has eigenvalues $\lambda_n = \left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)^2$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ and corresponding eigenfunctions
$$X_n(x) = a_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right).$$
Plugging in these eigenvalues to the boundary value problem involving $Y(y)$ gives
$$Y''(y) + \left(k - \left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)^2\right)Y(y) = 0.$$
Now we can split this up into cases where $k - (\frac{n\pi}{L})^2$ is either less than, equal to, or greater than 0. The only time there can be non-trivial solutions is if $k - (\frac{n \pi}{L})^2 > 0$, and it is then necessary to have that $k = (\frac{n \pi}{L})^2 + (\frac{m \pi}{W})^2$ where $m, n = 1,2,3, \ldots$ This is where I am getting confused. Is this BVP only solvable when $k$ takes the above form for fixed positive integers $m$ and $n$? I've consulted a few resources both in text and online and none of them seem to indicate this aside from one text I saw that was dealing with similar looking problems using eigenfunction expansions, and this method seems to yield the same result. Some of the resources I've seen (like the page on the Helholtz equation in cartesian coordinates on Wolfram mathworld) claim that the separation constant $\lambda$ has the form $m^2$, but I see no reason for this to be true. Could anyone let me know if my reasoning here is correct? Sorry if this is obvious, I haven't studied PDEs in quite a few years. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reasoning is correct. The eivenvalue is a sum of as many squares as the Cartesian coordinate system has axes. The format with a single square referes to the basic solution for the Laplacian along a line (not a rectangle). Discrete spectra with countably many eigenvalues are a standard for solving the Helmholtz or Schrödinger equation with boundary values forced to zero at the boundaries. Textbooks of quantum mechanics have many more examples of these.

Comment: So does this mean the Helmholtz equation in a rectangle is usually not solvable for any value of $k$ (the solvability of course depending on the domain)? For instance if we have the equation  
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} +u= 0$$
in the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with the same boundary conditions as originally stated, then since $1 \neq (m\pi)^2 + (n\pi)^2$ for any integers $m$ and $n$, this particular boundary value problem has no (non-trivial) solution?

Answer (score 0):

So far only the solutions in the space of separable (cartesian products) have been explored. There may be others proportional to some more complicated formats like u=exp(X(x)+Y(y)) or u=sqrt(X(x)^q+Y(y)^r) etc.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting, I had never thought of that before. Does this mean that if we look at a different boundary value problem we usually solve with separation of variables, say involving the heat equation, could have different eigenvalues outside of the ones that we usually get begin $\left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)^2$? Or does the uniqueness of the solution of that equation imply we only get those ones?